# Substring index with dashes

Tags: mysql, substring

I have this row in my table

[image]

I want to get the name **Mary Jane** only but for some reason its **Mary Jane-Jeyxa** that I'm getting.

**Descriptn** is my column name

Could you help me with this? :c

Here's my query:

```
  SELECT substring_index(substring_index(descriptn, ' ', -2), '-', -2) FROM `deposit`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substring_index(descriptn, '-', -2)` query returns last 2 parts splitted by `-` character, so: `Mary Jane` and `Jeyxa`

What you can do is split this again by `-` and pick the first part:

```
substring_index(substring_index(descriptn, '-', -2), '-', 1)
```

Comment: THIS DID THE TRICK :) Tnx